# display text on hover

Tags: html, css

When hovering over a  in html I want to display a text. Right now I have it this way:

```
echo "<td onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer; background-color:#ffeb3b'  title=$text id=$text></td>";
```

The problem is that it looks very small and without design.
How could I make it look bigger and with a little look?

I would like to do something similar to this in html.A box that appears on the right

[image: https://ayudawp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/tooltip.png]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp <- Does this help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For more information look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  transition-property: visibility;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it. First, create the main element, I'm using a text, and next to it add the text you wish to show on hover. Style everything according to your taste. Make sure you set the display of the extra text to `none`. Basically, we'll hide it and show it only when someone hovers over the main element.

Now, in the CSS, I've added `.Main-Text:hover + .Extra-Text` CSS Selector to achieve what we are trying to do. This basically means that when someone hovers on the element with class `Main-Text`, something will happen to the element with the class `Extra-Text`.

You can read about this more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered).

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.Main-Text:hover + .Extra-Text {
    display: block;
}

.Extra-Text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <div>
    <p class="Main-Text">
        Hover me to know more about me.
    </p>
    <div class="Extra-Text">
        <p>
        This is the extra information that will be displayed when the text is hovered.
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

I don't think so if this is something you are looking for but it's worth mentioning. You can use the `title` attribute in the HTML Elements to display some text when the user hovers over the element. Try it yourself. Run the snippet below and hover over the text.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <div>
    <p class="Main-Text" title="This is some extra text">
        Hover me to know more about me.
    </p>
    </div>
</html>
```